# Usage of Graceful and Gracious (and Grateful)

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Recently we came across a discussion (note: we are not native English speaker). In religious context (Christian to be specific), the Bible sometimes use the word `graceful`, and sometimes `gracious`. This confuses us, and looking at the Dictionaries and Google did not help at all.

> gracious: (in Christian belief) showing divine grace.
>
> graceful: having or showing grace or elegance.
>
> grace: (in Christian belief) the free and unmerited favor of God, as manifested in the salvation of sinners and the bestowal of blessings.

Could you please help us differentiate the two words? We also came across the word `grateful`, but we think we understand correctly, as `grateful` is used when we have something positive, and want to express our thanks.

About the details, when should we use `graceful` or `gracious`? Should we use `God is gracious`, or `God is graceful`?

Comment: Which version of the Bible uses graceful?? Full of grace, yes. Graceful, I don't know. Here is what I know about Christianity and the word /grace/. God bestows grace on people. A person can be full of grace. The Catholics say: Hail Mary, full of grace [God has bestowed grace on her]. Graceful in modern English means elegant. And gracious means polite in modern English. Personally, as a native English speaker and cultural Christian, I do not associate gracious and graceful with God.

Comment: God is the only power that can bestow grace. It  would be insulting (in a sense) to say God is gracious or graceful. When God bestows grace on a person, they are considered blessed by him.

Comment: I am sorry, I may be using the wrong sentence here. `God is gracious` or `God is graceful` is OUR (not Bible) way (in our language) *trying* to express that God give us grace though we do not deserve. That's why we need help with the word usage.

Comment: How do you know you are translating it correctly? You aren't. Because in English we say that people who have received God's grace, are "full of grace". I guess you can say they are "graceful" too. But we don't say in English that these people are "gracious". They are grace-filled people.

Comment: Psalm 145:8 (NIV): "The LORD is gracious and compassionate, slow to anger and rich in love." I meant this context. So we thought we could use the word for God? Which word then, should we use `God is [word]` when we want to say that He is generous in giving us grace/something?

Comment: God is generous in giving us grace. Just like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge (the book is large - it would help if you gave scriptures), but graceful generally is used with respect to an earthly object.

- 1 Cor 12:23 is sometimes translated using graceful; "and those which we deem less honorable we clothe with more abundant honor; and so our ungraceful parts come to have a more abundant grace, while our graceful parts have everything they need"
- Proverbs 5:19 refers to a graceful deer.

In the above cases, graceful is referring to the physical attributes of elegence, light-footedness, beauty, comeliness. You wouldn't generally apply these attributes to God, being without physical form.

Gracious, however, would be expected to be associated with God as it refers to his longstanding patience and un merited forgiveness. "God is gracious in that he does not give us the punishment that we deserve."

It is also possible that 'graceful' is being used instead of 'full of grace'. In such case you could, I believe, consider it a synonym of gracious.

Steve

Comment: One more question please, according to your answer, `gracious` can be used for human? For example, is it okay I say "She is gracious" or "Paul does everything graciously"?

Comment: When used with a human - it often takes on the meaning of generosity or kindness. A gracious host, for example, would be one that treats very well. Gracious words, would be kind words that may not be deserved. In all cases, grace suggests your getting more or better than you deserve - it is just that what you get tends to change based on the application.